# Ranges of floating point datatype in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I am reading a C book, talking about ranges of floating point, the author gave the table:

```
Type     Smallest Positive Value  Largest value      Precision
====     =======================  =============      =========
float    1.17549 x 10^-38         3.40282 x 10^38    6 digits
double   2.22507 x 10^-308        1.79769 x 10^308   15 digits
```

I dont know where the numbers in the columns Smallest Positive and Largest Value come from.

Comment: They come from the range of the floating-point type.

Comment: The correct but useless answer would be "IEEE 754".

Comment: Do you mean why are the limits those values?

Comment: Is IEEE 754 required by the C standard?

Comment: @foo: C does not require IEEE-754 floating-point.

Comment: As I expected, so no assumption about representation can be drawn from IEEE 754.

Comment: @foo, no. But the C standard provides optional features related to IEEE 754 (search for IEC 559 and IEC 60559 which are the IEC version of IEEE 754).

Comment: @foo, IEEE 754 formats are common and some books are prone not to make a difference between implementation characteristics and language required one and some people are prone not to pay attention when the book is clear that it shows characteristic of one or several common implementations that are not required by the language.

Comment: @AProgrammer Yet everyone here makes that assumption without mentioning that it's optional, and not necessarily the one that is used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These numbers come from the [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) standard, which defines the standard representation of floating point numbers. Wikipedia article at the link [explains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Range_and_precision) how to arrive at these ranges knowing the number of bits used for the signs, mantissa, and the exponent.

Answer (score 32):

A 32 bit floating point number has 23 + 1 bits of mantissa and an 8 bit exponent (-126 to 127 is used though) so the largest number you can represent is:

```
(1 + 1 / 2 + ... 1 / (2 ^ 23)) * (2 ^ 127) = 
(2 ^ 23 + 2 ^ 23 + .... 1) * (2 ^ (127 - 23)) = 
(2 ^ 24 - 1) * (2 ^ 104) ~= 3.4e38
```

Comment: Here I explain why the weird `-126` to `127` range which contains only 253 numbers and not the expected 255 (one is for infinity and the other subnormals): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204544/895245

Answer (score 9):

The values for the float data type come from having 32 bits in total to represent the number which are allocated like this:

1 bit: sign bit

8 bits: exponent p

23 bits: mantissa

The exponent is stored as `p + BIAS` where the BIAS is 127, the mantissa has 23 bits and a 24th hidden bit that is assumed 1.  This hidden bit is the most significant bit (MSB) of the mantissa and the exponent must be chosen so that it is 1.

This means that the smallest number you can represent is `01000000000000000000000000000000` which is `1x2^-126 = 1.17549435E-38`.

The largest value is `011111111111111111111111111111111`, the mantissa is 2 * (1 - 1/65536) and the exponent is 127 which gives `(1 - 1 / 65536) * 2 ^ 128 = 3.40277175E38`.

The same principles apply to double precision except the bits are:

1 bit: sign bit

11 bits: exponent bits

52 bits: mantissa bits

BIAS: 1023

So technically the limits come from the IEEE-754 standard for representing floating point numbers and the above is how those limits come about

Comment: Worth mentioning that that is the smallest normal one, there are smaller subnormals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204544/895245

Answer (score 5):

**Infinity, NaN and subnormals**

These are important caveats that no other answer has mentioned so far.

First read this introduction to IEEE 754 and subnormal numbers: [What is a subnormal floating point number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341395/what-is-a-subnormal-floating-point-number/53203428#53203428)

Then, for single precision floats (32-bit):

- IEEE 754 says that if the exponent is all ones (`0xFF == 255`), then it represents either NaN or Infinity.

  This is why the largest non-infinite number has exponent `0xFE == 254` and not `0xFF`.

  Then with the bias, it becomes:

  ```
  254 - 127 == 127
  ```
- `FLT_MIN` is the smallest *normal* number. But there are smaller subnormal ones! Those take up the `-127` exponent slot.

All asserts of the following program pass on Ubuntu 18.04 amd64:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float float_from_bytes(
    uint32_t sign,
    uint32_t exponent,
    uint32_t fraction
) {
    uint32_t bytes;
    bytes = 0;
    bytes |= sign;
    bytes <<= 8;
    bytes |= exponent;
    bytes <<= 23;
    bytes |= fraction;
    return *(float*)&bytes;
}

int main(void) {
    /* All 1 exponent and non-0 fraction means NaN.
     * There are of course many possible representations,
     * and some have special semantics such as signalling vs not.
     */
    assert(isnan(float_from_bytes(0, 0xFF, 1)));
    assert(isnan(NAN));
    printf("nan                  = %e\n", NAN);

    /* All 1 exponent and 0 fraction means infinity. */
    assert(INFINITY == float_from_bytes(0, 0xFF, 0));
    assert(isinf(INFINITY));
    printf("infinity             = %e\n", INFINITY);

    /* ANSI C defines FLT_MAX as the largest non-infinite number. */
    assert(FLT_MAX == 0x1.FFFFFEp127f);
    /* Not 0xFF because that is infinite. */
    assert(FLT_MAX == float_from_bytes(0, 0xFE, 0x7FFFFF));
    assert(!isinf(FLT_MAX));
    assert(FLT_MAX < INFINITY);
    printf("largest non infinite = %e\n", FLT_MAX);

    /* ANSI C defines FLT_MIN as the smallest non-subnormal number. */
    assert(FLT_MIN == 0x1.0p-126f);
    assert(FLT_MIN == float_from_bytes(0, 1, 0));
    assert(isnormal(FLT_MIN));
    printf("smallest normal      = %e\n", FLT_MIN);

    /* The smallest non-zero subnormal number. */
    float smallest_subnormal = float_from_bytes(0, 0, 1);
    assert(smallest_subnormal == 0x0.000002p-126f);
    assert(0.0f < smallest_subnormal);
    assert(!isnormal(smallest_subnormal));
    printf("smallest subnormal   = %e\n", smallest_subnormal);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/55ce88cdc3732702139c11d1448d508eaadfcf21/c/interactive/float_range.c).

Compile and run with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -o subnormal.out subnormal.c
./subnormal.out
```

Output:

```
nan                  = nan
infinity             = inf
largest non infinite = 3.402823e+38
smallest normal      = 1.175494e-38
smallest subnormal   = 1.401298e-45
```

Answer (score 2):

As dasblinkenlight already answered, the numbers come from the way that floating point numbers are represented in IEEE-754, and Andreas has a nice breakdown of the maths.

However - be careful that the precision of floating point numbers isn't exactly 6 or 15 significant decimal digits as the table suggests, since the precision of IEEE-754 numbers depends on the number of significant binary digits.

- `float` has 24 significant binary digits - which depending on the number represented translates to 6-8 decimal digits of precision.
- `double` has 53 significant binary digits, which is approximately 15 decimal digits.

[Another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765831/790070) has further explanation if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of the size of the exponent part of the type, as in IEEE 754 for example. You can examine the sizes with FLT_MAX, FLT_MIN, DBL_MAX, DBL_MIN in float.h.

Comment: is these macros are C standard macros ? Why I am asking is INT_MAX and INT_MIN are available in limits.h.

Comment: those don't seem to be available in limits.h