# What is the range of floats as used in C in different environments?

Tags: c, floating-point

The minimum range of the float datatype is 1E-37 to 1E+37. What is the maximum range of floats?

Comment: See the macros in http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Floating-Point-Parameters.html

Comment: The ranges for floating point types are defined in [float.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/float.h.html)

Comment: Have look [here][1] this may help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108053/ranges-of-floating-point-datatype-in-c

Answer (score 2):

As for the maximum of maximum floating types, the standard didn't specify them. What the standard specify is "the minimum of maximum".

> #### C11 §5.2.4.2.2 *Characteristics of floating types `<float.h>`* Section 12 & 13
>
> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by constant expressions with
>   implementation-defined values that are greater than or equal to those shown:
>   — maximum representable finite floating-point number, (1 − b−p)bemax

```
FLT_MAX  1E+37
DBL_MAX  1E+37
LDBL_MAX 1E+37

FLT_MIN  1E-37
DBL_MIN  1E-37
LDBL_MIN 1E-37
```

Answer (score 2):

The maximum range, and the range on all real-world implementations that matter, is `-INFINITY` to `+INFINITY`. One place it actually comes into play that the "range of representable values: for `float` includes the infinities (on implementations that support infinities) is that it's a constraint violation for a constant expression to be outside the range of values for its type, but that even something like `1e9999999999999999999999999999` is within the range of values for IEEE single-precision float, since the range is `-INFINITY` to `+INFINITY`. There's a defect report/interpretation detailing this issue somewhere, but I don't have the link handy.

Comment: +1 This answer makes me wonder about all the implementations, somewhere, that have the same bug as described in http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2012/11/19/Funny-floating-point-bugs-in-Frama-C-Oxygen-s-front-end . The mind boggles.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general maximum range. The C standard only specifies which range has to be covered at least. A compiler can support any greater range.

There is however a standard for floating types, [IEEE 754](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), specifying the behavior of floating point platforms in detail. This standard is usually applied.

According to that standard, the values are 1.4E-45 and 3.4E38.

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum range. An implementation is allowed to be arbitrarily generous. The only restrictions placed on floating point implementations are that:

1. The set of possible values of `float` is a subset of the set of possible values of `double`;
2. The set of possible values of `double` is a subset of the set of possible values of `long double`;
3. The set of all possible values of `float` (and thus `double` and `long double`) must include at least one finite number ≥ 1E37 and one finite number ≤ -1E37;
4. The set of all possible values of `float` (and thus `double` and `long double`) must include at least one positive number ≤ 1E-37 which is not zero;
5. The set of all possible values of `float` must include at least one positive number ≤ 1.0 + 1.0E-5 which is greater than 1.0; while the set of all possible values of `double` (and thus `long double`) must include at least one positive number ≤ 1.0 + 1.0E-9 which is greater than 1.0.

The last requirement does not strictly require `double` to be more precise than `float` since `float` *could* also include the same value.

However, an implementation may define the macro `__STDC_IEC_559__`. If it does, it needs to promise to implement the IEC-60559 standard (which is, in effect, IEEE-754); this commitment includes requiring `float` to be precisely the IEC-60559 single precision (32-bit) format, and `double` to be precisely the IEC-60559 double precision (64-bit) format. `long double` is not required to be an IEC-60559 format, but it must, as above, be a superset of `double` (or exactly the same type).