# Whether an implicit type conversion occurs between decimal literals and float types

Tags: c++

In C++,the type of floating-point literals is `double` by default;

```cpp
auto dval = 3.14;    // dval is a double
```

So,in the statement `float fval = 3.14` , `3.14 -> float` means `double -> float`?

---

Another similar question:

```cpp
float fval = ival + 3.14;
```

what type conversion is happening here

Comment: are you asking what is the official term for what happens in `float fval = 3.14;` ? I mean `float fval` certainly is a `float`.

Comment: It's an implicit cast - there's some details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145321/why-using-double-and-then-cast-to-float

Comment: what is `ival` ? The second question is also not quite clear

Comment: `3.14` is a `double`. `3.14f` is a `float`. Are you asking if `float fval = 3.14;` performs a conversion from `double` to `float` ?

Comment: @doctorlove There is no such thing as "implicit cast", casts are explicit conversions by definition.

Comment: In `float fval = 3.14`, `3.14` is a literal with type `double` that is implicitly converted to `float` and the result of that conversion used to initialise `fval` (or a result *as if* that conversion and initialisation occurred in sequence).   Some compilers issue warnings on this (e.g. a `double` can represent values that a `float` cannot, and the compiler may warn that converting `double` to `float` may lose precision).  Your second question is unclear, since you haven't specified what `ival` is.

Comment: If you use gcc or clang, add `-Wconversion` flag and see the output, you'll see what's happening.

Comment: It's not just decimal literals, also applies to hex literals like `0x1.p8` (==1.5 decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the declaration `float fval = 3.14` the initialiser is implicitly converted from double to float.

Comment: In my knowledge, implicit type conversion is small-to-large conversion, but double takes up more bytes than float. Why is there a conflict here?

Comment: @Yanyushen You seem to have misunderstood what an implicit type conversion means. It's also unclear what you mean by "conflict".