# Two floating point addition is not changing result

Tags: c, floating-point, addition, precision

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int loopCounter = 0;    
    float data1,data2;

    data1 = 2000.0f;
    data2 = 0.0001f;

    while(1)
    {               
      data1 = data1 + data2;
      printf("Loop Counter %d , Data %f\n",loopCounter,data1);
      loopCounter++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am running this code on Linux machine using the GCC compiler but if the addition of the 2 float reaches the value `2048.0` it does not change anymore.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: What do you mean with "halt"? Does it stop or does it continue to print same value?

Comment: Are you aware of precision limitation of floating point data types?

Comment: You mean it "halts" because it adds data2 without changing data1? Are you aware of the imprecision of float? Your code is perfect to find that special value, where the data2 is so small that its affect cannot be represented in the accumulator data1.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Please elaborate. Do not assume that "not changing anymore" means "not changing at all", or that "halt" means "not changing at all". The value at which changes stop occurring is likely to be higher than the init value.

Comment: `2000.0001` has more precision than `float` can hold (~7 digits for IEEE-754 single precision)

Comment: You should post the exact output of your program, not say vague things like "it halt" (what does this ever mean?)

Comment: halt means it continue to print same value "2048"

Comment: I have understood the root cause but can anyone tell how to avoid this in c code

Comment: @AvinashDane " how to avoid this in c code" --> Step 1:  Consider 2 things: 1) With _floating point_ numbers there are about as many representable `float` in the range [1.0..2.0] and ranges [1.0e-10..2.0e-10] and [1.0e+10..2.0e+10]. 2) All `float` take a a fixed about of memory, example 32 bits.  Does that make make sense to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any floating point value, in combination with a (much) smaller adding delta, there is a value from which adding the delta results in a value which is so "similar" to the previous one, that the representation in float is identical.

Your code is practically tailor-made to find that value.

So, while at first adding delta to 2000 and a few following values results in visible changes, your code will sooner or later (quite soon actually) reach the special value. Which I assume in your case is 2048.
`2048.0` and `2048.0001` have no different representation in float. Hence the adding has no effect on the variable.

Comment: I have understood the root cause but can anyone tell how to avoid this in c code

Comment: Cannot at all, you can only use wider floats in order to get the problem later.

Comment: You can however describe what you actually wan to achieve, in a separate question, show what you have (which is bount to be more/different than this) and ask for more specific help.

Comment: The application is the energy meter and I want to store the kWh accumulated value and for that I was using float as a data type. I know using double as a data type this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone has idea why this is happening?

Because of floating point precision.

Read [Ranges of floating point datatype in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108053/ranges-of-floating-point-datatype-in-c)

Notice that:

```
 2000.0001
```

*already exceeds* the limit a `float` can store (~7 digits for IEEE-754 single precision).

---

What happens in your case is that the precision is limited, which results in the "halting" issue you report. In other words, after some point, the adition doesn't have any actual effect (which is reflected to the user).

By that I mean that the new sum is *so close* to the previous sum, that their float reprecentation is the same, causing `data1` to store the same value.

In *your machine*, this value is 2048 and all the rest additions by a small δ do not affect the float representation of `data1`.