# The result is overflow and underflow of exp function in C

Tags: c, math

I'm learning C language, I read about `exp` function at: https://linux.cn/man3/exp.3.html

At `RETURN VALUE`, There are 2 cases:

- If the result underflows, a range error occurs, and zero is returned.
- If the result overflows, a range error occurs, and the functions return
     +HUGE_VAL, +HUGE_VALF, or +HUGE_VALL, respectively.

Could anybody please help me to explain these cases?

I wanna know that what input's value I have to use for `exp` function to occur these cases above.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What exactly is unclear for you in these two cases?

Comment: It depends on type you use. [Float and double have the following range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108053/ranges-of-floating-point-datatype-in-c), long double is more platform-dependent. [See this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/exp#Notes) for more info about error handling for these functions and acceptable values.

Comment: Floating point variables (`float`, `double`, etc) cannot represent just any value. For each type, there are limits on how small (close to zero) and on how large (far from zero) a floating point value can be. A calculation that would (mathematically) be smaller than the minimum possible is said to underflow - and `exp()` returns a zero value. Conversely, a calculation that gives a result that is (mathematically) larger than the maximum allowed is said to overflow - in that case, `exp()` returns the largest value that can be represented in the return type. [Note:  I'm oversimplifying]

Comment: I recomend doing your homework yourself. SO isn't a homework service. You can test ALL things by using trial and error. In this case it seems fairly safe to do. Alternatively use an analytic approach, meaning you should do the math. It's very easy.

Comment: Thanks all !  I'm using float type, I wanna know what input's value to result is underflow and overflow, please help me

Comment: If we start with `exp(log(x)) == x` (unbounded infinite precision), then `expf(logf(FLT_MAX))` would ideally be `FLT_MAX`. Consequently, `expf(nextafterf(logf(FLT_MAX), INFINITY)` would be *greater than* `FLT_MAX` in unbounded arithmetic. Consequently, the result would be `INFINITY`.

Comment: "I wanna know what input's value to result is underflow and overflow," --> try all `float`, there is only 4,000,000,000 of them It should a few seconds to a few minutes on a common computer.

Comment: i tried with Infinity + 1 and -Infinity - 1, but it look like incorrect.

Comment: I also try with value that out of float's range but it same as above

Comment: [32bit float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has finite exponent  <-126,127> and with denormalized values `-149` so `exp(-200)` should underflow and `exp(+200)` should overflow `float` with ease ...

Comment: Thanks all!, can anyone help me to explain the "result", what does it mean?